# Sorting by aggregate on large data set in real time

Tags: mysql, database, aggregate, scalability, bigdata

I would like to enable the users to sort videos by "most viewed" by period (day, week, month, year, etc).

Currently all the data is in MySQL and basically the setup is a "videos" table, and a "views" table which contains rows with a video_id, session_id and datetime column.

To sort by "most viewed" a computed field is generated for each video with COUNT() that counts all the view rows in the specified period. This works fine for periods like "hour" and "day" for now, but periods like "month" and "year" can take a long time.

The problem is that this isn't scalable. I have thousands of videos, and most videos generate thousands of views each month, which adds up to millions of views total each month.

I'm asking for a general solution/strategy which is scalable. Is stuff like this even doable in MySQL or should I consider a different database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For usage statistics (or logs) data the following aggregation strategy may be used:

- pre-calculate aggregates before some period (say, not including "today"). OLAP servers can do that, but of course you can do that in a simpler way with custom code if you don't need a generic solution. These aggregates should be re-calculated when period ends (for example, in the beginning of the day).
- to get actual results in the real-time, you need to perform aggregation only for "today". It will work fast, but if you have a lot of visitors, you can cache this aggregation too for short period of time (say, several seconds).
- when you need to select "most viewed" results, you need to combine pre-calculated aggregates (by all stats before today) and merge them with today stats aggregated in the real-time

Depending on your needs and requirements, this strategy may be used either on the database layer (you may create stored procedure that will pre-calculate aggregates and save them into special temporary table) or on application level (or both).